# Ideas for paid app in multiple markets

Tags: android, google-play

I have a situation that I have not seen addressed elsewhere, so I'd like to ask folks for ideas. Here's what's up:

I sell a relatively expensive (US$25) app that I have sold for 10 years in various forms on different portable platforms. In general it's pretty vertical-market oriented (astronomers, ham radio operators) but in some cases is of general interest and has sold pretty steadily over the whole time it's been around. I have an Android version ready to publish but am not sure the best route to take.

The issues that are troublesome for me are that it must be possible to download a free, time-limited but full-featured version for evaluation, and that I need to be able to sell it to previous customers at half-price (just a long-standing policy of mine.)

Note that I am already set up to sell from my own website - have been doing it with other versions of the software for years, and the app is already set up to run in "trial mode" until a registration code is entered.

I have been assuming that I would publish it on the Android Market as a free app, and add code to it to look for an "unlock key" app that I would publish there as well. The idea being that a person could download and test the app, and if they chose to purchase it could either buy the unlock key via the market, or could go to my web site and purchase a registration code, allowing a path for my "customer loyalty" discount.

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure this violates section 3.3 of the Developer Distribution Agreement: "All fees received by Developers for Products distributed via the Market must be processed by the Market's Payment Processor."

I have a couple of ideas, but I'd really like to hear some other opinions first. Sorry for the length - it's just a long question.

(Oh, and FYI, there is already a published iOS version of this app, and none of this is at all possible for it, and I think it's awful.)

Comment: I'm voting to move it to programmers. I believe it's better suited there.

Comment: If you had an 'unlock key' application, you could provide (specially built) APKs to your customers when taking the transaction through your website.

Comment: @Aleadam: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Andrew Koester: That would still violate section 3.3, since I would still be taking money from my website to unlock content that was downloaded from the Android Market.

Answer (score 0):

You could get them to buy the app at full price and then send the discount back to them - like a cash-back scheme. It's not very efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) to process the purchase. That way you won't violate any agreement.
2. You can publish more than one APK in the market, with different prices, and validate the install upon first run with a code you send them.

Comment: Re 1) Yes, that could work - I would have to set it up so the in-app purchase option for discounted pricing would only appear if you entered a "coupon code" that I had provided beforehand into the app. It's a market-only solution, tho - I'd need a different version of the app to sell myself - or in any other market, for that matter.

Comment: Re 2) No, that doesn't work. It would be easy to get into a situation where someone who didn't qualify for it had paid for the discounted version. Setting myself up for refunds is not a path I want to go down.

Comment: @jimk re 1) yes, it would be a market-only solution. But, if you want to sell the app yourself or in other market, then you don't have the issue of the android market policies. You would need to make two APKs for your app, one for the android market and one for selling it yourself. Bear in mind that many devices won't even be able to install an app outside of the markets. Re 2) You're probably right